# how to dynamically change data based on JSON file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<div id="rightside">
            <h1>Name Of Person</h1>
            <p>1900-1950
                <p><a href="linktowiki">Learn More</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur porta dictum turpis, eu mollis justo gravida ac. Proin non eros blandit, rutrum est a, cursus quam. Nam ultricies, velit ac suscipit vehicula, turpis eros sollicitudin lacus, at
                        convallis mauris magna non justo. Etiam et suscipit elit. Morbi eu ornare nulla, sit amet ornare est. Sed vehicula ipsum a mattis dapibus. Etiam volutpat vel enim at auctor.</p>
                    <p>Aenean pharetra convallis pellentesque. Vestibulum et metus lectus. Nunc consectetur, ipsum in viverra eleifend, erat erat ultricies felis, at ultricies mi massa eu ligula. Suspendisse in justo dapibus metus sollicitudin ultrices id sed nisl.</p>
                    <button>Pause</button>
        </div>
```

my div looks like this. I want to replace it with data that I am getting from a JSON file. However I only want to show 1 entry at a time and make it animate between entries (does not need to be fancy).

My question is how can I get jQuery to change between my JSON data?

My JSON data looks like

```
[
  {
    "name": "Elizabeth Cady Stanton",
    "image": "media/images/elizabeth.jpg",
    "year": "1815 – 1902",
    "wikilink": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Cady_Stanton",
    "article": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur porta dictum turpis, eu mollis justo gravida ac. Proin non eros blandit, rutrum est a, cursus quam. Nam ultricies, velit ac suscipit vehicula, turpis eros sollicitudin lacus, at convallis mauris magna non justo. Etiam et suscipit elit. Morbi eu ornare nulla, sit amet ornare est. Sed vehicula ipsum a mattis dapibus. Etiam volutpat vel enim at auctor. Aenean pharetra convallis pellentesque. Vestibulum et metus lectus. Nunc consectetur, ipsum in viverra eleifend, erat erat ultricies felis, at ultricies mi massa eu ligula. Suspendisse in justo dapibus metus sollicitudin ultrices id sed nil."
  },
```

I would appreciate any help or links to examples.

Thanks

Comment: Your HTML is malformed. The first two `<p>` tags don't have matching end tags.

Comment: Thank you but would would you be able to help with the jquery bit?

Answer (score 1):

Added `data-index` to track data index that we are showing

`<div id="rightside" data-index='-1'>..</div>`

It will change your data after every 5 seconds in rotating manner.

```
setTimeout(function(){
        var yourJsonData = [{"name":"Elizabeth Cady Stanton","image":""media/images/elizabeth.jpg"},{"name":"Elizabeth Cady Stanton","image":""media/images/elizabeth.jpg"}];
        var currentIndex = $("#rightside").attr('data-index');
        var totalLengthOfData = yourJsonData.length;
        var indexToShow = currentIndex+1;
        if(indexToShow > totalLengthOfData){
           indexToShow=0;
        }
        $("#rightside").attr('data-index',indexToShow);
        var dataToAppend =  yourJsonData[indexToShow];

        $("#rightside").children().remove();
        $("#rightside").append("<h1>"+yourJsonData['name']+"</h1>").
                        append("<p>"+yourJsonData['year']+"</p><p><a href='"+yourJsonData['linktowiki']+"'>learn more</a></p>"); 

     },5000);
```

haven't tested the code yet

Comment: Is the JSON data going to be coded with the JavaScript?

Comment: I believe data is coming from server side so you can make `ajax` request to get your JSON data

Comment: @softwareisfun If your JSON data is coming from your server, an API, a file, or otherwise being delivered in string format, use `var yourJsonData = JSON.parse([JSON string]);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var yourJsonData = '[{"name": "Elizabeth Cady Stanton","image": "media/images/elizabeth.jpg","year": "1815 – 1902","wikilink": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Cady_Stanton",            "article": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur porta dictum turpis, eu mollis justo gravida ac. Proin non eros blandit, rutrum est a, cursus quam. Nam ultricies, velit ac suscipit vehicula, turpis eros sollicitudin lacus, at convallis mauris magna non justo. Etiam et suscipit elit. Morbi eu ornare nulla, sit amet ornare est. Sed vehicula ipsum a mattis dapibus. Etiam volutpat vel enim at auctor. Aenean pharetra convallis pellentesque. Vestibulum et metus lectus. Nunc consectetur, ipsum in viverra eleifend, erat erat ultricies felis, at ultricies mi massa eu ligula. Suspendisse in justo dapibus metus sollicitudin ultrices id sed nil."}]'
        var obj = JSON.parse(yourJsonData);
        $('#rightside').find('h1:first').text(obj[0].name);
        $('#rightside').find('p:first').text(obj[0].year);
        $('#rightside').find('a:first').attr('href', obj[0].wikilink)
        $('#rightside').find('p:eq(3)').text(obj[0].article)
    });


</script>



<body>
  <div id="rightside">
            <h1>Name Of Person</h1>
            <p>1900-1950
                <p><a href="linktowiki">Learn More</a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur porta dictum turpis, eu mollis justo gravida ac. Proin non eros blandit, rutrum est a, cursus quam. Nam ultricies, velit ac suscipit vehicula, turpis eros sollicitudin lacus, at
                        convallis mauris magna non justo. Etiam et suscipit elit. Morbi eu ornare nulla, sit amet ornare est. Sed vehicula ipsum a mattis dapibus. Etiam volutpat vel enim at auctor.</p>
                    <p>Aenean pharetra convallis pellentesque. Vestibulum et metus lectus. Nunc consectetur, ipsum in viverra eleifend, erat erat ultricies felis, at ultricies mi massa eu ligula. Suspendisse in justo dapibus metus sollicitudin ultrices id sed nisl.</p>
                    <button>Pause</button>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by this:

HTML:

```
<div id="rightside">
<h1 id="nameOfPerson"></h1>
 <p id="year">
 </p>
<a id="wikiLink">Learn More</a>
<p id="article"></p>
<p></p>
<button id="fill">Start</button>
</div>
```

JQuery :

```
var dataObject = [{
"name": "Elizabeth Cady Stanton",
"image": "media/images/elizabeth.jpg",
"year": "1815 – 1902",
"wikilink": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Cady_Stanton",
"article": "Whole Article"
}];

$("#fill").click(function() {
setData(dataObject);
});

var setData = function(data) {
$.each(data, function(index, mainData) {
$("#nameOfPerson").text(mainData.name);    
$("#year").text(mainData.year);
$("#wikiLink").attr("href",mainData.wikilink);
$("#article").text(mainData.article)
});

};
```

By this code your data will be rendered dynamically.
For Demo you can check my fiddle :
[Fiddle Link Here](https://jsfiddle.net/etfc5jdx/14/)